# Node.JS Edit User Button Goes to the Same User

Tags: html, node.js

I'm having an issue in which my edit button on my user table goes to the same user (I'm doing it by the _id value).

Edit - my routing code:

```
router.get('/admin', function (req, res) {

  User.find({}, (err, users) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }).then((users) => {
    res.render('pages/userTable', {users: users});
  })

});
```

My code:

```
  <table id="users" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Created</th>
        <th>Edit User</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


      <% users.forEach(user => { %>
        <% if (user.enabled == true) { %>

                <form method="get" action="users/<%- user._id %>" id="myform">
                <tr>
                 <td><%- user.name %></td>
                 <td><%- user.username %></td>
                 <td><%- user.created_at %></td>
                 <td><input type="submit" name="" value="Remove User" form="myform"></td>
                 </tr>
      <% } %>
      <% }) %>

  </tbody>
  </table>
```

My pictures:

[image]

[image]

The Remove User button should lead to whichever user I clicked on, but it always leads to Tom Test.

What's my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you better change

```
<input type="submit" name="" value="Remove User" form="myform">
```

By an

```
<a href="/user/<%= user._id %>" />
```

instead an  input and form with medthod GET...

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have checked your code and i think you are facing this issue because of you didn't close form tag. Once you will close form in your code you won't get this issue.